# Running Ruby Script via shell() function

Tags: ruby, r, shell

I'm trying to (eventually) execute a ruby script via R by calling the shell() function. As a first step though, I am simply trying to verify that I can call the ruby compiler via this function, and I am getting an error. Here is my code:

```
dir <- shell("ruby -v", intern=TRUE)
```

This throws a warning: Warning message: running command

```
'C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c ruby -v' had status 1
```

And the 'dir' variable is blank. I have verified that the command "ruby -v" works when run in a command prompt, and that Ruby is included in my system path variables.

Comment: I know you said Ruby is in your system path variables but can you verify that you see ruby in the `PATH` environmental variable in R with `Sys.getenv("PATH")`?

Comment: what shell are you using? what happens if you specify the shell in the shell command.  try setting intern=FALSE, wait=TRUE and see what the output is in the console

Comment: @cdeterman Thank you, that was the issue. I didn't even know R had an internal path environment variable. I added the Ruby /bin directory via the Sys.setenv() function and I now get the proper output of the Ruby version from the shell() command. Thanks!!

Comment: @NathanCalverley, I will add answer below so we can close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to confirm that the ruby path is within `PATH` environmental variable using `Sys.getenv("PATH")`.  If it isn't, you can always add it as you stated above with `Sys.setenv`.

Here is a way to simply append the `PATH` variable with a new directory.

```
Sys.setenv(PATH = paste(Sys.getenv("PATH"), "/my/ruby/dir/bin", sep=":"))
```

I'm not aware of a more concise way to append a path to an existing environmental variable from within R.